# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (25x340 and 360x1)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I get this error message and I'm not sure why. My input is (batch, 1, 312) from tabular data and this CNN is constructed for a regression prediction. I worked out the shapes for each step with the formula `(input + 2*padding - filter size)/stride + 1` as in the comment below. The problem appears to occur at  `x = self.fc(x)` and I can't figure out why. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
class CNNWeather(nn.Module):
    # input (batch, 1, 312)
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNNWeather, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=8, kernel_size=9, stride=1, padding='valid')         # (312+2*0-9)/1 + 1 = 304
        self.pool1 = nn.AvgPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)                                                      # 304/2 = 302
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=8, out_channels=12, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding='valid')        # (302-3)/1+1 = 300
        self.pool2 = nn.AvgPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)                                                      # 300/2 = 150
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=12, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding='valid')       # (150-3)/1+1 = 76
        self.pool3 = nn.AvgPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)                                                      # 76/2 = 38
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=16, out_channels=20, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding='valid')       # (38-3)/1+1 = 36
        self.pool4 = nn.AvgPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)                                                      # 36/2 = 18  (batch, 20, 18)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=20*18, out_features=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool1(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool2(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.pool3(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        x = self.pool4(F.relu(self.conv4(x)))
        print(x.size())
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)               # flatten   (batch, 20*18)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the input size of your FC layer:

```
self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=20*18, out_features=1)
```

The output of the previous layer is 340, so you must use `in_features=340`.

These are the shapes of the output for the third and fourth layers.

```
torch.Size([5, 16, 73]) conv3 out
torch.Size([5, 16, 36]) pool3 out
torch.Size([5, 20, 34]) conv4 out
torch.Size([5, 20, 17]) pool4 out
```

Notice that out of the "pool4" layer come 20x17, meaning 340 elements.

Comment: Thank you very much. Double checked my calculations and I made a simple math error at 304/2.